# How to route all 404 URLs to a view or page in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently reading up on routing in asp .net but I cannot seem to find any easy explanation on how to route all URLs to a single page or controller action in ASP .NET

Here is the code that I currently have which contains the standard routing.

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
            if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
                _ = app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            _ = app.UseStaticFiles();

            _ = app.UseRouting();
            _ = app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
                _ = endpoints.MapControllers();
                _ = endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
```

I tried using `UseStatusCodePages` methods and co. but it seems to redirect me to the page  or viewinstead of actually mapping directly to the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's a setting for [custom error pages in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use `endpoints.MapFallbackTo` methods and such, e.g.

```
            _ = app.UseStaticFiles();

            _ = app.UseRouting();
            _ = app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
                _ = endpoints.MapControllers();
                _ = endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
```